# Change image source URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried to do some research to no avail. I think it has to do with the fact that I want to do a hard code change versus changing a directory of the URL. I have some poorly written image source URL's from an old web host that need to be redirected to the new host. Example below:

I need all images that are http://www.domain.com/images/moreinformation.jpg to pull the image from http://www.differentdomain.org/blog/image/moreinfo.jpg.

Note that the URL's are entirely different and on different domains/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Since the URL's are entirely different, you'll need to create a rule for each one of them. In the htaccess file in the document root of your old domain, add, for each image, lines like this:

```
Redirect 301 /images/moreinformation.jpg http://www.differentdomain.org/blog/image/moreinfo.jpg
Redirect 301 /images/anotherimage.jpg http://www.differentdomain.org/blog/image/another.jpg
```

etc.